# .net core 2 - unique key constraint violation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm getting a

> "SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Organization' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

error when saving an `Organization` that already exists in the database. If the `Organization` is new, it goes through without any issue - the `Organization` is created in the `Organization` table and the reference to it is properly created in the ASP NET `Users` table.

```
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Organization currentOrg = new Organization();

            var existingOrg = _context.Organization.Where(m => m.OrganizationName == model.Organization);

            if (existingOrg.Count() > 0)
            {
                //currentOrg = _context.Organization.Find(existingOrg.First().Recno);
                currentOrg = existingOrg.First();
            }

            else
            {
                currentOrg.OrganizationName = model.Organization;
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName
                , AddToConstantContact = model.AddToConstantContact,
                Organization = currentOrg, CityId = "1" };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id.ToString(), code, Request.Scheme);
                await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Its because you are adding an Entity (Organization) to a *new* ApplicationUser.  Since the ApplicationUser is new (will generate an INSERT statement), all child entities are considered new as well.  To avoid this either assign the Org after the User is created, or only set the OrganizationID of the ApplicationUser during creation - leave the Organization property null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how to give credit... but Sam's response was correct - the following code fixed the issue:

```
            if (existingOrg.Count() > 0)
            {
                //user.Organization = new Organization();
                user.OrganizationId = existingOrg.First().Recno;
            }

            else
            {
                user.Organization = new Organization();
                user.Organization.OrganizationName = model.Organization;
            }


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public String CityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
}
```